# python regex prevent nonetype error

Tags: python, regex, arcpy

I have code below that searches for a pattern and assigns the pattern to a variable `num` if the pattern exists.

```
for row1 in cursor1:
    try:
        m = re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)", row1[0])
        num = m.group()
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

I then use the `num` variable in the code below:

```
z1=(item for item in numlist if item[6]==num and harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<150)
```

I would like to eliminate the num variable and compare text that matches the regex directly to `item[6]` as in `if item[6]==re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]).group()` But of course this will give me an error for the rows that don't have the pattern. How do I achieve what I am trying to do without getting the `nonetype has no attribute group()` error? 
PS: The overall code not shown here loops through rows, creates tuples and assigns necessary values based on fulfillment of the if statement. I want to change the regex matching part shown in the code for better performance because not all rows use the `num` variable. I want the regex to be run only for the rows that use this variable.

Comment: put the assignment of `item[6]` inside of a `try` block and the comprehension inside of your `else` block for the aforementioned try

Comment: "*NoneType* has no attribute group" - I'm sure you know how to check for `None`...

Comment: @R Nar unfortunately I can't go that route because item[6] is being generated inside the comprehension and I am using generators so I need it to be where it's at.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath I am sorry but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Do you want to assign value of num to item[6] or compare it in the if condition?

Comment: @Roshan Jossey I want to compare the value of num to the value of item[6] to see if they are the same.

Comment: @Roshan Jossey I edited my question. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Karoly Horvath has pointed out, you can make use of the fact that text that doesn't match returns None object

```
In [2]: m = re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)", row1[0])
Out [2]: None
```

You can use this in if condition

```
z1=(item for item in numlist if (re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]) and item[6]==re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0]).group()) and harversine.myhaversine(custx,custy,item[2],item[3])<150)
```

return value of `re.search(r"^[0-9]+(?=\s)",row1[0])` ie, `None` will evaluate to false making value of whole condition false.

Comment: Pleasure to know it worked for you. I liked the bit where you corrected the typo in my edit